# Server config / PHP that cause 1 letter PHP array to fail?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there such a thing as a configuration option for PHP or anything on a web server for allowing or not arrays that looks like this:

`$i['addme']["A".$temp[1]] = $v;`

For some reason, this code was working on a Netfirms server and now I changed to a VPS host and it doesn't keep the value...

Any idea why?

=============

## EDIT 1 : more details below:

The exact code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $temp = explode("_", $k);//_p($temp);
    if ($temp[0] == "ATTRIBUT") {
        $i['addme']["A".$temp[1]] = $v;

        // debugging test below
        echo $v;  // THIS WORKS
        echo $i['addme']["A".$temp[1]]; // EMPTY DATA
    }
}
```

- When I print the content of the POST array, I see my data.
- When I print the content of the `$temp` array, I see my data
- RIGHT after assigning the `$v` data to `$i['addme']`, I check it and its empty.

In other word, in this script, when I check the $v string, it shows the data, but when i echo the $i string, its empty...

Ideas?

=============

## EDIT 2 :

I just tested `$ii` (2 letter variable) instead of `$i` and it worked... Why?

Side note : I still want to solve the problem, I don't want to go in my 20 000 lines of code to change all my 1 letter arrays...

=============

## EDIT 3 :

Strangely, when I put `$i = array();` before the script, it works.

Why?

Comment: Have you considered other potential causes of failure? What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: Perhaps their default error reporting level is higher then your previous configuration. Are you defining $temp and does $temp[1] exist before you try to use it? Are you expecting $temp[1] to ever be null/blank?

Comment: "doesn't keep the value" --- is not a good explanation

Comment: I just added more details in the description, can you help me out?

Comment: Good question.  I think folks get offended because Rock is trying to set up a hypothesis a bit early (server configuration) ... but is a curious problem and would be frustrating.  +1

Comment: Can you get $i['addme'] to retain ANY value?

Comment: No, just `$i['addme']`doesn't retain any value.  CORRECTION, when I test the SAME script as above on ANOTHER page, it works... wow now I'm more confused...

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know the cause, since it could lead to other problems that would be difficult to trouble shoot later on... And well, we human MUST know ;)

Comment: Do you reuse your variable names, like $i?  So there is some weird difference in scope and the empty value is bleeding in from elsewhere?  Like in HP Lovecraft?  Just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: This `exact` script works well on many other servers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the author points indirectly to the answer: He says something like "if I use $i, I've a problem but if I use $ii, that's ok". It's $i used before for something else? $i is defined as an array and initialized before first use? The code fragment the author presents is called from any other control structure at a higher level?

Comment: Arg. I found the cause. God. 8 straight hours of coding through the night to find it. $i was indeed used before this file, in which it was defined as a string... I added a last minute change to a file that I `include()` before this script and I forgot about it. My software (Macrabitt Espresso) automatically complete simple php functions like, in this case the `for ($i = 1; $i < $x; $i++){}` I added in the include. As you notice, the `$i` came from there, and I didn't notice since it was `automatically` added by the software. 8 hours lost on that... but thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm not patronizing you but after more then 30 years coding in many languages, some lessons I learned. One is "never use a single letter variable name" because is prone to errors; another is "isolate code as much as possible"; yet another: when time arrive to debugging, impersonate Sherlock Holmes. Good luke.

Comment: Wow Joel, what a journey what a night.  Tell me, did you resolve the issue of why this server and not others?

Comment: Thanks José, I'll look into that. Smandoli, the issue was present on this server because I had to change a specific bit of code regarding the $_SERVER variables... The only thing that was changed, and it was supposed to be 'insignificant', ;)

Answer (score 0):

well first take a look upon all the post variables does they contain "ATTRIBUT_XXX" where XXX is some value. because there is a possibility that your post field just contains ATTRIBUT_ or ATTRIBUT and it doesn't have 2nd value in it.

it may be possible that your error reporting is disabled or loose like it doesn't return any warnings to you

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to pay attention to the information given in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `ATTRIBUT_12` where `12` is simply the attribute ID for another database table. Since I'm echoing the $v value and it works (which would be 12 in this example) but the `$i['addme']["A".$temp[1]]` doesn't, this is not the source of the problem...

Comment: change your loop's variable or this one

Answer (score 0):

try to run this snippet in your server and tell the details

```
$_POST = array('ATTRIBUT'=>'hello','ATTRIBUT_efg'=>'how','ATTRIBUT_xyz'=>'are you');
$i = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $temp = explode("_", $k);//_p($temp);
    if ($temp[0] == "ATTRIBUT") {
        $i['addme']["A".$temp[1]] = $v;

        // debugging test below
       // echo $v;  // THIS WORKS
        echo $i['addme']["A".$temp[1]]; // EMPTY DATA
    }
}
print_r($i);**strong text**
```